# Is there any possible way to not let it take up space in the home page as my logo is pushed with this hidden back icon

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Here is the code i used:

[image]

Is there any possible way to not let it take up space in the home page as my logo is pushed with this hidden back icon.
I used the Scaffold and TopBar. And also using navigating Host. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please edit your question by replacing code image with formatted code. More info can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3585796)